# In MySql how do I export null values from an sql string in a csv file as double quotes ("")?

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, export

I will try to keep this short and into the point.

My goal is to export data into a CSV file using PhpMyAdmin export button.
Some of the data from the database fields are empty and I want those empty (null) fields to be shown in the CSV file as "" (double quotes).

I have tried using the CASE WHEN command but I am still recieving just nothing between the data. Here is the SQL code I used.

```
 SELECT 
   CASE WHEN gift_message is null 
   THEN "\"\"" 
   ELSE gift_message 
   END 
 FROM `th_orders` 
 WHERE perfect_processed = 0;
```

This return just empty values into the csv file instead of "" as I want.
Any help is greatly aprecciated.

Comment: Apparently if instead of "is null" I use " = "" " it seems to work!

Comment: Read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: There is some confusion here between empty strings and NULL. There's actually nothing wrong with the query if you are testing for NULL, however the data consists of empty strings , not NULL as your question implies, hence the empty string test works when IS NULL doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could use the `ifnull()` function and `''`

```
  SELECT 
     IFNULL(gift_message, '') 
   FROM `th_orders` 
   WHERE perfect_processed = 0;
```